# if UITextField clicked

Tags: ios, events, callback, uitextfield

I am doing an application and I need to detect when a `UITextField` is clicked. I tried using `touchesBegan` but it doesn't react to textfield when clicked, only outside of it. I am only starting with Objective-C so if you give me advice, please let it be detailed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  // Do something
}
```

As long as the text field has interaction enabled and is editable. However, a second tap will not be detected if the text field is already the first responder.

Comment: Thank you for answer, however this does not work. I posted this code with NSLog to see if it recognises the click and it doesn't. I'm not sure if I did it right though. I just posted the code in the app delegate.m and instead of "//do something", I wrote "NSLog(@"test");". No matter where I click, nothing gets displayed in console.

Comment: Did you set the textField delegate properly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know I have to set a delegate and I'm not sure how and where.

Comment: Try reading a bit about delegation and about the objects you are using. Here's a tutorial on UITextField: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate--mobile-10943

Comment: Thank you. I read it and added a delegate to my text field. After that I placed the code you posted to viewController instead of delegate and now it works like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the textview's delegate property to an object that overloads the `textViewShouldBeginEditing:` function.  You could also use the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` function of the same delegate.